# Django. on_delete.model.SET() - установить ссылку на объект в виде функции с параметрами

Tags: django, django-model

В описании модели одно из полей представляет **ForeignKey**-ссылку на другой объект. Параметр поля `value` в подстановке `on_delete = models.SET(value)` может быть как значением, так и ссылкой на фукцию.

В данном случае необходимо в этой фукции установить параметр `self` чтобы вычислить номер привязываемого объекта.

Модель данных представляет собой web-страницу с контентом различного типа. Объекты контента на странице имеет некоторый порядок, реализованный односторонней привязкой к предыдущему объекту. Если какойто из объектов удаляется в ходе редактироваия страницы то следующий за ним объект должен привязаться к предыдущему относительно удаляемого, т.е. по принципу односвязного списка.

**models.py**

```
class Page(models.Model):
    """ Страница с контентом. """
    title = models.CharField('Заголовок', max_length=256)
    content = models.ManyToManyField('Content')
    # ...

class Content(models.Model):
    """ Модель контента страницы Page. """
    # корневой объект контента на странице
    is_root = models.BooleanField('Начальный?', default=False)
    # ссылка на предыдущий контент страницы
    previous = models.ForeignKey(
        'self'
        , null=True
        , default=None
        , related_name='next'
        , on_delete=models.SET(get_previous(self))
    )
    # ...
```

Здесь поле `previous` является ссылкой на собственный объект - предыдущий контент. В случае удаления связанного объекта необходима перепривязка.

Я пытаюсь реализовать перепривязку с помощью функции **get_previous(`self`)**, чтобы по объекту`self` узнать страницу и в ней перепривязать объекты контента.

```
def get_previous(self):
    """ Возвращает ссылку на другой предыдущий контент после удаления связанного. """
    # ...
    return pk
```

**Проблема.**

Параметр `self` в контексте `on_delete = get_previous(self)` не распознаётся Django - `Unresolved reference 'self'`.

Каким способами можно обойти эту ошибку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self не распознаётся потому что у вас он ни где не передан. Попробуйте реализовать ваш функционал в методе класса, где уже будет self. К примеру:

```
class Test:
    ...
    
    def method(self):
        return ...
```

Comment: Да, именно так я и сделал!